# salesforce regex for emails converted to oracle pl/sql

Tags: regex, oracle, email, plsql

I know I shouldn't be using regex to validate email addresses, but i need something in place that will ensure the nightly directonal sync back and forth to salesforce does not fail on an invalid email address

according to this [salesforce knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170904&language=en_US), they use the following regex to validate their email addresses

```
REGEX ( UPPER ( EmailField__c ) ,"^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$")
```

however if i try to convert this reghex for oracle use, it simple does not work, the regexp_like never returns (note i had to double the single quote to escape the string )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION valid_email_web (p_email in varchar2)
                                      return string is
  v_return  varchar2(255);
  email_regexp constant varchar2(1000) := '^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&''*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';

BEGIN
  if regexp_like(upper(p_email),email_regexp,'i') then
     v_return := p_email;
  else
     v_return := null;
  end if;
  return v_return;

END;
```

i attempted the not regexp_like as well, and it did not work either

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add some example addresses that failed (alter them of course) and explain how they failed.

Comment: @Gary_W every email address failed, whether it was well-formed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after removing an unneeded backslash in front of the pipe (not needed when inside of the character class brackets) and the dot in front of the domain.  Also ony one single quote is now needed due to the alternate quoting method method used (also known as the q-quote mechanism).  It would be interesting to test with your addresses that failed failed though.

EDIT: The `UPPER()` around the passed-in address is not needed when using the case insensitive flag to regexp_like so I changed the example.

```
select 1 
from dual
where regexp_like( 'test@test.com', 
                   q'[^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{\|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$]', 'i');
```

I'm not sure I would restrict domains to 4 characters though unless you have specific requirements: [list of top level domains from ICANN](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

Comment: Where would I remove the 4 character domain ? the {2,4}? thanks for the help here, sadly my knoweldge of regex is limited

Comment: The last `\.[A-Z]{2,4}` means restrict what comes after the last literal period character to at least 2 but not more than 4 characters in the set of `[A-Z]`.